# .EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

```
I have a scenario where 
1) While creating a Role, I can add permissions
2) While creating a Permission, I can add Roles.

Data Model:
ROLE : ROLE_ID(PK), DESCRIPTION
PERMISSION: RESOURCE_ID(PK), DESCRIPTION
ROLE_PERMISSION: ROLE_ID, RESOURCE_ID, ALLOWED : PK is --> (ROLE_ID,RESOURCE_ID)

So I have following Uni-directional OneToMany relations in JPA:

class Role{
.......
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Set<RoleResourcePermBean> resourceAssociations = new HashSet<RoleResourcePermBean>();
}

class Permission{
.......
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_ID")
    private Set<RoleResourcePermBean> roleResourcePermLocal = new HashSet<RoleResourcePermBean>();
}

class RolePermission{
@Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private String role;
    @Column(name = "ALLOWED")
    private String allowed;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "RESOURCE_ID")
    private Integer resourceId;
}
```

So in create Role flow, I am adding RolePermission to Role bean and called Persist on Role bean. This triggered the persist from both Role and Permission(due to cascade), hence got the error EntityExistsException.
Same case with UPDATE ROLE flow.
Also same case with PERMISSION create and update flows.

If I remove cascade on any of beans(Role, Permission), then create/update works, but not in another bean.
For ex: If I remove cascade in Permission, then create/update role works. But fails with diff error with create/update of Permission(as cascade doesn't happen) and vice-versa.

Could you please any help me here.
Are mapping are correct? I tried with bi-directional @ManyToOne, encountering same issue as mentioned above.

Comment: If I change CASCADE option from ALL to MERGE on both Role and Permission beans, it does works well with UPDATE flow. But it fails for CREATE flow(as I would be using entityManager.PERSIST on Role / Permission bean). So how to make sure both Create/Updates works for both Role and Permissions.? please help.